# Improving performance by caching or delegate call?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to improve performance in the code below and kinda know how but not sure which is the best approach.
The first hit will take longer but subsequent hits should be quicker. Now, I could cache T (where T is a class) and then check the cache to see if "T" exists, if so - go ahead and get its related information (NamedArguments) and go through each of the NamedArguments and finally if the criteria matches, go ahead and set the value of the current property.

I just want to make it more efficient and performant. Any ideas?

```
var myProps = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(MyCustomAttribute)) && prop.CanWrite && prop.GetSetMethod() != null);

foreach (var currentProperty in myProps)
{
    foreach (var currentAttributeForProperty in currentProperty.GetCustomAttributesData())
    {
        foreach (var currentNamedArgument in currentAttributeForProperty.NamedArguments)
        {
            if (string.Equals(currentNamedArgument.MemberInfo.Name, "PropName", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                currentAttribParamValue = currentNamedArgument.TypedValue.Value == null ? null : currentNamedArgument.TypedValue.Value.ToString();

                // read the reader for the currentAttribute value
                if (reader.DoesFieldExist(currentAttribParamValue))
                {
                    var dbRecordValue = reader[currentAttribParamValue] == DBNull.Value ? null : reader[currentAttribParamValue];

                    // set it in the property
                    currentProperty.SetValue(val, dbRecordValue, null);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

DynamicMethods or ExpressionTrees will be much* faster than reflection. You could build a cache of all property getter/setters for a type, and then cache that information in a `Dictionary` (or `ConcurrentDictionary`) with type as the key.

- [Expression Tree Basics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx)
- [Dynamic Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx)

### Flow

- Discover type information (e.g. on app startup).
- Compile dynamic methods for each property (do all properties at once).
- Store those methods in a metadata class (example follows).
- Cache the metadata somewhere (even a static field is fine, as long as access is synchronized). Use the type as the key.
- Get the metadata for the type when needed.
- Find the appropriate getter/setter.
- Invoke, passing the instance on which you wish to act.

```
// Metadata for a type
public sealed class TypeMetadata<T> {

    // The compiled getters for the type; the property name is the key
    public Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> Getters {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // The compiled setters for the type; the property name is the key
    public Dictionary<string, Action<T, object>> Setters {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

// rough invocation flow
var type = typeof( T);
var metadata = _cache[type];

var propertyName = "MyProperty";
var setter = metadata[propertyName];

var instance = new T();
var value = 12345;
setter( instance, value );
```

### Example Setter

Excerpted from [Dynamic Method Implementation](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/08/06/late-bound-invocations-with-dynamicmethod/) (good article on the subject).

I can't vouch that this *exact* code works, but I've written very similar code myself. If you aren't comfortable with IL, definitely consider an expression tree instead.

```
public static LateBoundPropertySet CreateSet(PropertyInfo property)
{
    var method = new DynamicMethod("Set" + property.Name, null, new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object) }, true);
    var gen = method.GetILGenerator();

    var sourceType = property.DeclaringType;
    var setter = property.GetSetMethod(true);

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // Load input to stack
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, sourceType); // Cast to source type
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // Load value to stack
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, property.PropertyType); // Unbox the value to its proper value type
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, setter); // Call the setter method
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var result = (LateBoundPropertySet)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(LateBoundPropertySet));

    return result;
}
```

<sup>*25-100x faster in my experience</sup>

Comment: Just to add this article that covers this a little bit https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates.aspx

Comment: @user629926 - thanks for the link. John's approach in that article is really easy and doesn't require manual IL generation (though that can be useful for more complex implementations).

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is notoriously slow in loops, so some kind of caching would probably help. But to decide what to cache, you should **measure**. As the famous saying goes: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"; you should make sure that you really need to optimize and what exactly to optimize.

For a more concrete advice, attributes are attached at compile time, so you could cache a type and a list of its propertyInfos for example.

Comment: I agree with your comment about "premature optimization i the root of all evil". Oh I know that very well but I know caching will improve this greatly! I just wondering what I should cache - I know it would be a Dict of some kind - maybe <T, NamedArguments> ?

Comment: I think I'd use something like Lookup<Type, PropertyInfo>. Lookup is a multimap, so where a Dictionary stores key-value pairs, lookup store key-collection-of-values. Something like Dictionary<Type, List<PropertyInfo>> but made easier. The question is how/where you want to store it. If you do this over lots of types and store statically, it could eat up quite a bit of memory. But that's for your consideration, you know your system the best :)

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar problem once - reflection is extreemely slow.
I used caching, like you are planning and performance grow more than **10 times**. It was never again be a bottleneck in performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've created similar logic before where I've cached an 'execution plan' for each type encountered. It was definitely faster for subsequent runs but you would have to profile your scenario to see whether it's worth the extra code complexity and memory usage.